# SwiftUI: how to replace or hide ToolbarItem

Tags: swift, swiftui

In one of the views, coming from the 3rd-party SDK, the view has a toolbar in the navigation bar:

```
struct ThirdPartyView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hi!")
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to replace or hide this item in this toolbar. But it appears that if I define a new toolbar in my view, it's just added to an existing toolbar:

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ThirdPartyView()
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.down")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(The result of the above is 2 buttons in toolbar, instead of one)

The NavigationStack is outside of both views:

```
struct DisplayedView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            MyView()
        }}}
```

Note: yes, it's my guess that placement is defined as navigationBarLeading in the view. I tried other relevant placements as well (navigation, cancellationAction).

So is it possible to replace or hide a `ToolbarItem`?

Comment: You can use a conditional statement inside a `ToolbarItem` or `ToolbarItemGroup`; could that achieve what you need?

Comment: you can use `.toolbar(.hidden)` but that hides your control as well. As a hack you can then add your controls manually (i.e. not with .toolbar). If you're on macOS you can define your own `accessoryBar<ID>(id: ID)`that can be individually hidden or shown.